# Send data of one process to another process utilizing messages (Linux)

Tags: c, process, signals, sleep, wakeup

I need to write a process in C that takes a user's name via keyboard. When he presses enter, the process goes to sleep. I then need a second process to wake up upon receiving the message, saves the user's name in a file, then goes to sleep and sends a signal to the 1st program that it's done, which in turn wakes up the first program.

I know I'm supposed to use signals and message IDs, but I'm not clear on how to tackle the communication between processes.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void m.signal(int x)
{
    printf("A signal has arrived.");
}

int main()
{
    signal(100, m.signal);

    while(1)
    {
        pause()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can certainly use signals for this, though if the two processes are parent/child you may find it much easier to just use a pipe, as you'll get the data xfer channel as a freebie bonus without having to setup something else.

Comment: What does `m.signal` mean? Does seems to be valid C code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interprocesscommunication can be done with `Pipes`. For windows see [Interprocess Communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For Linux I'd suggest to read [Inter process communication using named pipes(FIFO) in linux](http://tuxthink.blogspot.de/2012/02/inter-process-communication-using-named.html) .